# I have a problem when running "npm run build" on cPanel

Tags: vue.js, cpanel

I'm encountering the following error:[RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: wasm memory]

I've tried running "npm cache clean --force" with the following warning:

npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

Here's the full error message:

[vuexy-vuetify-vuejs-admin-template@7.0.1 build

> npm run build:icons && vite build

[vuexy-vuetify-vuejs-admin-template@7.0.1 build:icons

> node resources/js/@iconify/build-icons.js

Bundled icons from /home/project
Bundled icons from /home/project
Bundled 10 icons from resources/images/iconify-svg
Saved /home/project/resources/js/@iconify/icons-bundle.js (1588379 bytes)

node:internal/process/promises:279
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^

[RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: wasm memory]

I've tried uploading and extracting the "build" folder to the "public" directory, but I'm still encountering issues.

Comment: It's quite possible that the server doesn't have enough ram to build an app.